# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() when using phpGACL

Tags: php

Using phpGACL with `db_type = "mysqli"` in `gacl.ini.php` still got below error,

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_pconnect()"

when create `gacl` class but `phpGACL` admin works fine.

```php
<?php
    include ("gacl.class.php");
    $gacl = new gacl();
?>
```

I expect it should work fine as `phpGACL` admin do.

Comment: Seems like you are using an old version of gacl together with PHP 7+. Are you sure you have the up-to-date version of your class?

Comment: Yes, I am upgrade my server from php5 to php7.

Comment: [mysqlp_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) is deprecated since PHP 5 and has been removed in PHP 7.

Comment: Any solution ? I expect phpGACL should switch ADODB to use mysqli driver base on gacl.inc.php config.

Comment: Yes, the ADODB driver in the GACL repo is over 13 years old. (When I got the correct repo). You can try to replace it by the PHP 7 compatible version from [here](https://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:php7_status)

Comment: I have already replaced ADODB with latest release 5.20.14 but no help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I make a small patch to make it work.
Change the code in gacl.class.php line 110.

```
function gacl($options = NULL) {
```

to

```
function __construct($options = NULL)
```

When create a gacl object, it must passing the db_type parameter instead of rely on gacl.ini.php setting.

```
$gacl = new gacl(array("db_type"=>"mysqli"));
```

Modify gacl.class.php line 455, remove & sign

```
$row =& $rs->FetchRow();
```

to

```
$row = $rs->FetchRow();
```

Modify profiler.inc line 37, 180

```
function Profiler( $output_enabled=false, $trace_enabled=false);

$tmp=split(" ",microtime());
```

to

```
function __construct( $output_enabled=false, $trace_enabled=false)

$tmp=explode(" ",microtime());
```

In order to make build in GACL admin work perfectly, also need to update ADODB, Smarty2 to latest version 2.6.31 (Smarty 3 is not compatible). acl_debug.tpl line 42 add @ sign to count function.

```
{if @count($acls) gt 0}
```

@ sign to by pass count uncountable error as a quick fix. Need further study the code for long term solution.

Fix a bug in group_admin.php

```
$formatted_groups = $gacl_api->format_groups($gacl_api->sort_groups($group_type), HTML);
```

to

```
$formatted_groups = $gacl_api->format_groups($gacl_api->sort_groups($group_type), 'HTML');
```